# Loading a page using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using `jQuery`. My main page is `index.php`. on load of this page. How do i load another page internally. say a small block in the page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the load command. For a simple page like this:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>test</title
</head>
<body>
   <div id="content"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

you could fill the Div with id = content like this:

```
$('#content').load('yourUrl.php');
```

EDIT: changed from get() to load()

the syntax for the get command would be:

```
$.get('yourUrl.php', function(data){
   $('#content').html(data);
 });
```

Comment: [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) is a different function, you want [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) here :)

Comment: yeah your right... guess my brain doesn't work that well on a sunday ;)

Comment: y cant we use .get() over here...that will also fetch data rite ?... can i pass parameters to .load() function?

Answer (score 8):

Like this: `$('.smallBlock').load('targetUnderSameDomain.php .anotherSmallBlock');`

In the first part you select the block where you want to insert the block of the targeted file.
The load function has two parts:
The first part is where you select the targeted file, the second is optional, but there you can select an element within the targeted file's html.